# what is the indefinite integral of $\int \frac{x^n}{x+1}\ dx$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve $\int \frac{x^n}{x+1}\ dx$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried a couple of things like trigonometric substitution and by parts but somehow it didn't help much.

Comment: It is $$\frac{x^{n+1} \, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x)}{n+1}+C$$

Comment: Hey would you mind giving me a proof?

Comment: For an odd $n$, $(x^n + 1)/(x+1)$ is a polynomial; for an even one, so is $(x^n-1)/(x+1)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is this another computer-generated answer? It's really meaningless.

Comment: The hypergeometric answer is just a Lerch transcendent and a special case of the incomplete beta function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just substitute $y=x+1$ and use the binomial formula:

$$\int \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx = \int \frac{(y-1)^n}{y}dy $$
$$= \int \frac 1y \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk y^{k}dy$$ $$ = \int\frac{(-1)^n}{y}dy + \sum_{k=1}^n\int(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk y^{k-1}dy$$
$$= (-1)^n\ln |y| + \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{k}\binom nk y^{k} (+C)$$
$$= (-1)^n\ln |x+1| + \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{1}{k}\binom nk (x+1)^{k} (+C)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
I_n = \int \frac{x^n}{x+1}dx = \int \frac{x^{n-1}(x+1)}{x+1} dx - I_{n-1} =\frac{x^n}{n} - I_{n-1}
$$

etc., with $I_0 = \log (x + 1)$

Answer (score 2):

$\int \frac {x^n}{x+1} dx$

$x = u-1\\
dx = du$

$\int \frac {(u-1)^n}{u} du$

$\int \frac {(-1)^n}{u} + \sum_\limits{k=1}^n {n\choose n-k+1}(-1)^{n-k+1} u^{n-k}\ du\\
(-1)^n \ln (x+1) + \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose n-k}(-1)^{n-k} \frac {(x+1)^{n-k}}{n-k}$

Comment: Thanks guys I got this :)